# JAVA how can I replace scnr.next() with the arrays in txt file to avoid user to type thousands of times?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, java.util.scanner

I noticed that the user has to input variables a lot in order to accomplish this. User needs to type 90 times according to this code. I heard I can use File, PrintWriter to allow Scanner to read txt contents in an array form. I looked up bunch of tutorials but it is hard to achieve my goal. Do you mind me helping me out how to replace my scnr.next() to arrays from the txt file?

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class midtermBc3Choe{

   public static void main (String [] args){

    int workerNum = 30;
    int jobNum = 5;
    int monthNum = 6;

      System.out.println("There are 2 criteria to consider per job.");
      System.out.println("There are" + jobNum + "jobs for a person per month.");
      System.out.println("Tell a worker's quality of his job by useing word 'good' or 'bad.'");

      double correctEachTask[][][] = new double [workerNum][monthNum][jobNum];
      double correctMonthly[][] = new double [workerNum][monthNum];
      double correct6Month[] = new double [workerNum];

      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0 ; i < workerNum ; i++){//workers
         for(int j=0; j< monthNum; j++){//month
            for(int k=0; k< jobNum; k++){//jobs
               boolean criteria1 = false;
               boolean criteria2 = false;
               String string1 = scnr.next();
               String string2 = scnr.next();

               if( string1.equals("good") && string2.equals("good") ){
                  criteria1= true;
                  criteria2 = true;
                  correctEachTask[i][j][k] = 1.0;
               }
               else if( string1.equals("good") && string2.equals("bad") ){
                  criteria1 = true;
                  criteria2 = false;
                  correctEachTask[i][j][k] = 0.5;
               }
               else if( string1.equals("bad") && string2.equals("good") ){
                  criteria1 = false;
                  criteria2 = true;
                  correctEachTask[i][j][k] = 0.5;
               }
               else{
                  correctEachTask[i][j][k] = 0.0;
               }
            }//end - task -each
         }// end j - month -each
      }//end k - workers - each


      for(int i= 0; i< workerNum; ++i){
         for(int j = 0; j < monthNum; ++j){
            double accum =0;
            for(int k =0; k < jobNum; ++k){
               accum += correctEachTask[i][j][k];
            }//for k - monthly avg correct
             correctMonthly[i][j]=accum/jobNum;
         }//for j- month - monthly avg correct
      }// for i - workerNum -monthly avg correct

      for(int i =0; i < workerNum; ++i){
            double accumMonthlyAvg =0;
         for(int j= 0; j < monthNum ; ++j){
            accumMonthlyAvg += correctMonthly[i][j];
         }// for j - month - 6 month avg correct
            correct6Month[i] = accumMonthlyAvg/monthNum;
      }// for i - workerNum - 6 month avg correct

      System.out.print("workers' monthly average: ");

      for (int i =0; i < workerNum; ++i){
         for(int j = 0; j < monthNum; ++j){
       System.out.print(correctMonthly[i][j]);  
         }    
      }//print out montly average

      System.out.println(" ");
      System.out.print("worker 6 month average: ");
      for (int i =0; i < workerNum; ++i){
          System.out.print(correct6Month[i]);
      }//print out 6 month average


   }//main

}//class
```

////////this is how my input.txt looks like currently

```
good good good good good
good good good good good
good bad good good bad
good good good good good
bad bad good good bad
bad bad good good bad
bad bad good good bad
bad bad good good bad
good good good good good
good good good good good
good bad good good bad
good good good good good
bad bad good good bad
bad bad good good bad
bad bad good good bad
bad bad good good bad
good good good good good
good good good good good
good bad good good bad
good good good good good
bad bad good good bad
bad bad good good bad
bad bad good good bad
bad bad good good bad
good good good good good
good good good good good
good bad good good bad
good good good good good
bad bad good good bad
bad bad good good bad
```

Comment: So wrap your `Scanner` around a `File` instead of `System.in`.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have gotten.  .

- Replace your `Scanner` with `BufferedReader` to read the file.
- Loop through all the lines in the file and append them to a `StringBuilder` variable while looping.
- Once finished, use the `split` method to obtain an array that holds all the words.
- Now, you can just loop the array you have obtained. The zeroth element in the array will be your `string1` and the first element will be `string2` in your first triple nested for-loops and so on...
- Note that the number of words is 120. Your triple nested for-loops will run (30*6*5) = 900 times. This will cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.
- Also, your `criteria1` and `criteria2` are not being used.

Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int workerNum = 30;
    int jobNum = 5;
    int monthNum = 6;

    System.out.println("There are 2 criteria to consider per job.");
    System.out.println("There are" + jobNum + "jobs for a person per month.");
    System.out.println("Tell a worker's quality of his job by useing word 'good' or 'bad.'");

    double correctEachTask[][][] = new double[workerNum][monthNum][jobNum];
    double correctMonthly[][] = new double[workerNum][monthNum];
    double correct6Month[] = new double[workerNum];

    BufferedReader br = null;//Use BufferedReader instead Scanner.
    String rawData = "";//This will store all the text read from the file.
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
        //Read the file until the end, then store the text read in rawData.
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        rawData = sb.toString();//here, convert the StringBuilder to normal String
        br.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Example.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Example.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    //Now, we will split the long text whenever there is a space ie " ". We will obtain an array
    //that will have all the "words" that you are looking for.
    String[] cleanData = rawData.split(" ");
    //check everything is read correctly.
    for (int i = 0; i < cleanData.length - 1; i++) {
        System.out.println(cleanData[i]);
    }
    //Here, we will create a counter to loop through the array we obtained earlier.
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < workerNum; i++) {//workers
        for (int j = 0; j < monthNum; j++) {//month
            for (int k = 0; k < jobNum; k++) {//jobs
                boolean criteria1 = false;
                boolean criteria2 = false;
                //if reached the end of file
                //without this if statement, your program will crash.
                if (counter >= cleanData.length - 1) {
                    return;
                }
                //read the zeroth element
                String string1 = cleanData[counter];
                counter++;//increase the counter to read the first element
                String string2 = cleanData[counter];
                counter++;//increase the counter to read the second element once it loops back.
                if (string1.equals("good") && string2.equals("good")) {
                    criteria1 = true;
                    criteria2 = true;
                    correctEachTask[i][j][k] = 1.0;
                } else if (string1.equals("good") && string2.equals("bad")) {
                    criteria1 = true;
                    criteria2 = false;
                    correctEachTask[i][j][k] = 0.5;
                } else if (string1.equals("bad") && string2.equals("good")) {
                    criteria1 = false;
                    criteria2 = true;
                    correctEachTask[i][j][k] = 0.5;
                } else {
                    correctEachTask[i][j][k] = 0.0;
                }
            }//end - task -each
        }// end j - month -each
    }//end k - workers - each

    for (int i = 0; i < workerNum; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < monthNum; ++j) {
            double accum = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < jobNum; ++k) {
                accum += correctEachTask[i][j][k];
            }//for k - monthly avg correct
            correctMonthly[i][j] = accum / jobNum;
        }//for j- month - monthly avg correct
    }// for i - workerNum -monthly avg correct

    for (int i = 0; i < workerNum; ++i) {
        double accumMonthlyAvg = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < monthNum; ++j) {
            accumMonthlyAvg += correctMonthly[i][j];
        }// for j - month - 6 month avg correct
        correct6Month[i] = accumMonthlyAvg / monthNum;
    }// for i - workerNum - 6 month avg correct

    System.out.print("workers' monthly average: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < workerNum; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < monthNum; ++j) {
            System.out.print(correctMonthly[i][j]);
        }
    }//print out montly average

    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.print("worker 6 month average: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < workerNum; ++i) {
        System.out.print(correct6Month[i]);
    }//print out 6 month average

}//main
```